# Subversion master-slave replication

Tags: svn

I'm trying to set up a local SVN server to work with.
Im using Visual SVN Server that uses Subversion 1.7 and Apache 2.2.20

Copying data from Master rep to Slave works perfectly(via **svnsync**), but when i'm trying to commit something it returns error

> svn: E160013: Commit failed (details follow):
>
> svn: E160013: '/svn/local/!svn/me' path not found

My local server url is

> https://nb-grpe:8443/svn/local/

If i remove SVNMasterURI - everything works perfectly, but i get commit to slave :(

Does anybody know what can this "!svn/me" mean ?

Thanks

Comment: you can't commit to mirror, only to master